# Valid to use url for http POST method, instead of body after header?

Tags: http, post, query-string

Need help understanding the http specs clearly to get a black & white answer on what to support/code. 
HTTP/1.1 RFC 2616 & RFC 723x

Do we need to support reading the query string on an http POST method request 
-or- only read the body (as discussed in 2616). This previous post doesn't talk about reading query string: [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)
it seems we just ignore query, look only at content type & body. But I'm being told by a tech that new spec needs query to now be inspected also.